# AdventureWorks 2008--where to find Customer names

Tags: sql-server-2008, adventureworks

I'm using the AdventureWorks 2008 sample database to do some testing and teaching. The Sales.Customer table is linked to the Sales.SalesOrderHeader table, as I'd expect, but I can't figure out where the rest of the Customer data (like Name) is stored.

When I poke around for documentation, it refers to a Sales.Individual table, but I don't see that one.

Not sure it matters, but I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sales.Customer (PersonID) is a foreign key to Person.Person (BusinessEntityID). You'll find the related data in the Person.* tables.

Comment: Thanks, thought that was the case, but something made me question it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  pp.FirstName+ ' '+pp.MiddleName+' '+' '+pp.LastName As Full_Name 
From Person.Person  pp 
Inner Join 
HumanResources.Employee em
On pp.BusinessEntityID = em.BusinessEntityID ;
```

Or If you dont want to concat the strings as Full Name 
Use The Below Query

```
Select  pp.FirstName ,pp.MiddleName ,pp.LastName
From Person.Person  pp 
Inner Join 
HumanResources.Employee em
on pp.BusinessEntityID = em.BusinessEntityID ;
```